# click() works fine in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm testing the following piece of Javascript code on the Console before I include it into my application (I found it on SO)

```
pom = document.createElement('a')
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent("Hello World!"))
pom.setAttribute('download', "IEpomTest")
pom.style.display = 'none'
document.body.appendChild(pom)
pom.click()
document.body.removeChild(pom)
```

This is working fine on Chrome and the pom.click() downloads a text file with "Hello World!" in it, but when I try it on IE11, the "pom.click()" takes me to this URL "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Hello%20World!" and I get the error message "The webpage cannot be displayed".

Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems like IE does not support data:text/plain urls.

Comment: IE doesn't support the `download` attribute ([Can I use: download](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)). I suggest looking into [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE will try to open as a website, a better approach might be checking if `window.navigator.msSaveBlob` is present, and if is, [Using this method to download the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. This worked like a charm